# How to get String from spinner Android

Tags: java, android, json, spinner

ihave json that i put on my spinner as below :

```
   {
    "data": [
        {
            "kode": "1",
            "text": "No Tujuan"
        },
        {
            "kode": "2",
            "text": "Broadcast Admin PUPI"
        },
        {
            "kode": "3",
            "text": "Broadcast TIM PUPI"
        },
        {
            "kode": "4",
            "text": "Broadcast Semua PUPI"
        },
        {
            "kode": "5",
            "text": "Broadcast Ketua KUB"
        },
        {
            "kode": "6",
            "text": "Broadcast Operator PUPI"
        },
        {
            "kode": "7",
            "text": "DJPT - Executive"
        }
    ]
}
```

when display in spinner, it display the "text" but when user click on spinner,it will give "kode", but everytime i click my spinner, it just give "text" not "kode",this is how i load my spinner :

```
public class SpinnerType extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Modul_sms_broadcast.this);
        dialog.setTitle("");
        dialog.setMessage("melakukan pengambilan data...");
        dialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String url ="http://10.10.2";
         JSONArray data = null; 
    try {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        data = json.getJSONArray(real_data);
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            r1 = c.getString(real_rel1);
            r2 = c.getString(real_rel2);
            tipe_sms.add(new spin(r1, r2));

            System.out.println(r2);
            System.out.println(r1);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        dialog.dismiss();
         ArrayAdapter spinnertype = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_style, tipe_sms);
         spinnertype.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
         spinner1.setAdapter(spinnertype);

            code=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(code.equals("1")){
                nomor_sms.setFocusable(false); 
                nomor_sms.setClickable(false);
            }
            else {
                nomor_sms.setFocusable(true); 
                nomor_sms.setClickable(true);
            }

    }
}
public class spin {
      String kode;
      String text;

      public spin(String n, String c) {
        kode = n;
        text = c;
      }

      public String toString() { 
        return text; 
      }
    }
```

is there anywrong with my code? i hope someone can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: where you are adding `setOnItemSelectedListener` to spinner?

Comment: tostring method only return text , use this to get code and text both public String toString() { 
        return kode+","+text; 
      }

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i'm not adding setOnItemSelectedListener   i just add : code=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK why your answer missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its return only text because of:

```
public String toString() { 
        return text; 
      }
```

**EDIT :**

just change to:

```
public String toString() { 
        return text+" "+kode; 
      }
```

For getting code from selected Item:

```
code=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
int start = code.lastIndexOf(' ');
String codeval = code.substring(start+1);
```

Comment: i want to display in spinner with text

Comment: well as you see, i want to get string from "kode"

Comment: @Aoyama have you tried my code.? you can get Kode from string using it.

Answer (score 2):

tipe_sms u can use for any text. for text u can use position from onItemSelectedListener on spinner and then u can get spin object of that location and now u can get kode or text easily.hope u understood what i am saying.